# Array formula across columns and for entire column?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm a google sheets beginner and need some help. I am using a sheet that is populated by a google form, so it's a bit tricky for me.

The google form allows users to select up to three options - red, blue, green. They must select one and can select three, so the output in column A can be "red" or "red, blue" or "red, blue, green" or any combination.

I've figured out how to split the answer combination using the formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(trim(SPLIT(A2, ",")))` so I get the individual outputs without the commas (that the google form returns) across up to three columns.

But - since it's a google form, I also need to have this formula automatically pasted as new rows are added to the sheet from the form. I can't figure out how to do a "double" array formula (for additional columns for data output **and** additional rows as data input) or if that's even an option or if I'm missing something here. Any help? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use in row 1:

```
={"formula", "header", "row"; ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, ","))))}
```

or in row 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, ","))))
```

---

fully dynamic formula for row 1 would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"fx", IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A2:A"&COLUMNS(SPLIT(A2:A, ","))))))); IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, ","))})
```